# AWS security groups connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have some security groups in `AWS EC2` which I need to clean up.

Is there a command in `aws-cli` to show what resources are connected to respective security groups?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe thats beginner's question, but if I try to delete a group that is used somewhere, will aws console display a message that it cannot be deleted?

Comment: Yes, if you try to delete a security group that is in use, AWS will give you an error message. In the AWS web console it will show the resources using the security group when you try to delete it.

Comment: does this help https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-find-security-group-resources/

Comment: Thanks Jatin, that's what i need.